# Dynamic Widget Canvas Sizing in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, widget

When I add a Widget object to a BoxLayout in a .kv file, it does what I expect and fills the available space at the top of the screen.  However, when I add the Widget dynamically in Python, it doesn't appear at the top of the screen nor does it take up the full remaining space of the screen as I would expect.

I created a small sample program to demonstrate my issue.

When I add a Widget object to a BoxLayout in a .kv file, it does what I expect and fills the available space at the top of the screen.  Here is the kv file and the resulting screen:

KV FILE

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos:  self.pos
    Button:
        size_hint: .5, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        height: 100
        text: 'My Button'
```

RESULTS:

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6KaL.png)

When I take the Widget out of the kv file and try to add it dynamically into the BoxLayout when the button is clicked, it doesn't appear at the top of the screen nor does it take up the full remaining space as expected.

NEW KV FILE (test.kv):

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        size_hint: .5, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        height: 100
        text: 'My Button'
        on_release: app.on_btn_release()
```

PYTHON:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root
    
    def on_btn_release(self):
        wid = Widget()
        wid.size_hint = (1,1)
        with wid.canvas:
            Color(rgb=(1,0,0))
            Rectangle(size=wid.size, pos=wid.pos)
        self.root.add_widget(wid, 1)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

RESULTS:

[Bad Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yprgD.png)

I tried shifting the canvas instructions to be after the add_widget() call, but that didn't help.  I know that the problem is that, at the time the instructions are added to the canvas, the Widget hasn't yet been resized to fill the box layout.  I know that because, if I add a second button which adds the canvas instructions and click that after the first button is clicked, it works fine.  I'm just wondering how I can do this on the first button click.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the problem is that at the moment that you execute the `canvas` instructions, the widget size and position are its initial default values. Defining the canvas instructions in python does not setup any bindings to make adjustments to those `canvas` instructions when the widget size and/or position change. One way to solve this is to set up those bindings, like this:

```
def on_btn_release(self):
    wid = Widget()
    wid.size_hint = (1, 1)
    with wid.canvas:
        Color(rgb=(1, 0, 0))
        Rectangle(size=wid.size, pos=wid.pos)
    wid.bind(size=self.wid_changed)
    wid.bind(pos=self.wid_changed)
    self.root.add_widget(wid, 1)

def wid_changed(self, wid, new_attr):
    wid.canvas.clear()
    with wid.canvas:
        Color(rgb=(1, 0, 0))
        Rectangle(size=wid.size, pos=wid.pos)
```

You could also define a custom widget with a rule in the `kv` that defines the `canvas` instructions, so that `kv` sets up the bindings for you.